# WebGL: How to scale an object by a vector, or produce this result (image included)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm essentially trying to figure out how to scale an object irrespective of it's local rotation. I could produced this result with morph animation, but I would hope for something more robust.
[image: a rotating ball being flattened]

Answer (score 0):

The axes of a mesh's scale property are aligned with its local co-ordinates, so could you just use that?

```
mesh.scale.x = Math.sin(t * w) * 0.25 + 1.25;
mesh.scale.y = -Math.sin(t * w) * 0.375 + 1 - 0.375;
mesh.scale.z = Math.sin(t * w) * 0.25 + 1.25;
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/botolagain/jce3U/

Comment: Rotate your example around the X or Z axis and you'll see it does not produce my desired result.